# JWPlayer, Soundcloud file source

Tags: javascript, loops, soundcloud, jwplayer

Does JWPlayer support the file source from soundcloud?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        jwplayer("mainplayer").setup({
            playlist: [{
                file: "https://soundcloud.com/hucci/desire-remix"
                }],
            primary: "flash",
            height: 30,
            width: 370,
            autostart: false,
        });
    </script>
```

This seems to be an unanswered question across the board. I'm hoping someone dedicated such as "Ethan JWPlayer" can answer this one, or provide a possible work-around! Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JW Player can handle self-hosted videos, i.e., you give it a link directly to an MP4 or stream, and YouTube videos. That's all. It doesn't support any other third-party players, which is what things like Soundcloud, Vimeo, etc., are.

This is not an "unanswered question." It's been answered repeatedly, both here and on the JW Player support pages.

Comment: After checking through several sites it seemed that people were gliding around the answer rather than providing something of use. Either way, I could not find a viable answer and have missed these questions. Thanks for the swift answer, +1.

Comment: Indeed, this is all we support - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-support

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can play Soundcloud files with JWplayer or with any other player (jPlayer/basic HTML5 player), just keep in mind that you must place a Soundcloud logo and link to the track page on Soundcloud.

To do that you will need to use the [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com), first go and register a new app to get your client-ID, and then you can link to the track using the ID of that track and a type of 'mp3'.

For example this will load JWplayer with a track from Soundcloud with the ID of "123456":

```
jwplayer('audioPlayer').setup({
    height: '30',
    file: 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/123456/stream?client_id=abcdefg123456789',
    type: 'mp3'
});
```

You can use the [Soundcloud SDK](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks) to get all the information of the tracks using regular Soundcloud links, first include the SDK script:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>
```

Then use the resolve function with your Soundcloud track/playlist/user URL:

(To get info of playlists and users, replace "track" with "playlist" or "user".)

```
SC.initialize({client_id: 'abcdefg123456789'});

var url = 'https://soundcloud.com/artist-name/track-name';

SC.resolve(url).then(function(track){
    console.log(track.stream_url);
});
```